# C++ converting back and forth from derived and base classes

Tags: c++, casting

I was wondering if there is a way in C++ to accomplish the following:

I have a base class called `ResultBase` and two class that are Derived from it, `Variable` and `Expression`. I have a few methods that do work on `vector<ResultBase>` . I want to be able to pass in vectors of `Variable` and `Expression` into these methods. I can achieve this by creating a `vector<ResultBase>` and using `static_cast` to fill it with the members from my vector of Variable/Expression. However, once the vector has run through the methods, I want to be able to get it back as the vector of Result/Expression. I'll know for sure which one I want back. static_cast won't work here as there isn't a method to reconstruct a Variable/Expression from a `ResultBase`, and more importantly I wouldn't have the original properties of the Variables/Expressions

The methods modify some of the properties of the `ResultBase` and I need those changes to be reflected in the original vectors. (i.e. `ResultBase` has a property called `IsLive`, and one of the methods will modify this property. I want this `IsLive` value to be reflected in the derived class used to create the `ResultBase`

Whats the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vector<ResultBase *>` should fix your slicing problem - a `vector<ResultBase>` will never contain classes derived from `ResultBase`, but rather copies that "slice off" e.g. `Expression` by copying the `ResultBase` part of it.

See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) for a detailed explanation of slicing.

Comment: This is of course correct, but I think the OP is aware of it: *and more importantly I wouldn't have the original properties of the Variables/Expressions*.

Comment: @Jon: Better explain too much than too little - The next guy finding an answer in search may *not* know this

Comment: Agreed. I 'm just saying that the answer may not be very useful to the OP as it stands.

Comment: @Jon: `vector<T *>` is the obvious way of solving this though - for more specialized solutions we'd need more specialized information.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to change your functions that do work on `vector<ResultBase>` into function templates that do work on `vector<T>`, with `T` a template parameter. To be even more generic, perhaps the functions can operate on a pair of iterators instead of a particular container type.

You can then call them with a `vector<Variable>` or `vector<Expression>` instead of a `vector<ResultBase>`, as long as `Variable` and `Expression` are both proper substitutes for `ResultBase`, as a derived class should be.

Alternatively as Erik says you can use pointers to get polymorphic behavior with containers. For ease of memory management, a vector of smart pointers or a Boost `ptr_vector` is usually preferred to a vector of raw pointers.

There's no way to convert an instance of a derived class to base and then back to derived, while preserving its original value, for pretty much the same reason that it's not possible to convert from `int` to `char` and then back, preserving the original value. If all else fails, you could perhaps bodge something together where you use the modified `ResultBase` objects to somehow update the original `Variable` or `Expression` objects with any changes made by the functions.